# MediaCodec decoding to surface natively

Tags: android, android-ndk, android-mediacodec

I am using MediaCodec's decoder to output data to a surface. Using the .configure function, I passed a surface created through surfaceComposerClient. The problem is that the codec fails to start. I presume this is an issue with the way my surface is setup (when I set surface to NULL the codec starts)

Looking at MediaCodec decoder java examples it seems like I need to create an EGL backed SurfaceTexture. Is it possible to natively create a surface texture using C++/NDK? Are there any examples out there of this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I assume this is not a "normal" app, since you're interacting with SurfaceFlinger directly.

You can find examples in some internal OpenGL tests -- the code was fixed up for the 5.0 Lollipop release.  Take a look at the [San Angeles demo](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/native/+/lollipop-release/opengl/tests/angeles/), which uses the [WindowSurface](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/native/+/lollipop-release/opengl/tests/lib/WindowSurface.cpp) class to get a surface from SurfaceComposerClient.

You don't need a SurfaceTexture, or do anything with EGL, to decode a video to a surface.  Surfaces have a producer-consumer structure, and EGL and MediaCodec are two different examples of producers.  (SurfaceFlinger is the consumer.)

It's never easy to know why MediaCodec is failing.  You can try drawing on the surface with GLES to see if it's valid, but my guess is that your problem is elsewhere.

For a SurfaceTexture, the app is both the producer and the consumer; it provides a way to decode the video to a surface that you can then manipulate as a GLES texture.  This adds unnecessary overhead if you just want the video to play on screen.

Answer (score 0):

refer to SimplePlayer.h&.cpp in Android-4.4 source code. it's used to decode an media file and output decoded video into surface. i think it is similar with your scenario.